# Retrieve secure copy in UNIX?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, remote, scp

Is there a way to retrieve a secure copy in UNIX?

Why would I need to do this?  Because I can login to a remote machine from my local machine, but not the other way around.  So I need to retrieve a secure copy instead of just using `scp` to send a file from my remote machine to my local machine.

Comment: What's the difference between "retrieve a secure copy" and "use scp to send a file from remote to local"? Why is the latter not sufficient?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`scp` can be used both to copy to a remote machine, **and from one**:

I assume you are used to using:

```
scp localfile USER@REMOTE:remotefile
```

But you can also use it to do:

```
scp USER@REMOTE:remotefile localfile
```

Comment: Worked!!  Is there a way to get this to append to that local file, however?

Comment: To my knowledge, not without going via a temporary file

Answer (score 1):

To append a remote file to a local one, improving [Andrewe Stubbs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24865987/841108) copy to local stdout and append that:

```
 scp USER@REMOTE:remotefile /dev/stdout >> localeppendedfile
```

or simply (assuming a Posix remote machine)

```
 ssh USER@REMOTE /bin/cat removefile >> localeppendedfile
```